# plesk+ tomcat + mod_jk + jsp gives 404

Tags: tomcat, mod-jk, jsp

I trying to install myhello-world.war to plesk tomcat5, I doing "install java webapp", but when i go http://domain.com/mytomcat-helloworld/pages/myhelloworld.js I getting:

```
404

/mytomcat-helloworld/pages/myhelloworld_jstl.jsp

java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mytomcat-helloworld/pages/myhelloworld_jstl.jsp
    at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.getPageState(JSPEngine.java:330)
    at jrun.jsp.Translator.translate(Translator.java:67)
    at jrun.jsp.JSPEngine.translateJSP(JSPEngine.java:708)
    at jrun.jsp.JSPServlet.translate(JSPServlet.java:125)
    at jrun.jsp.JSPServlet.service(JSPServlet.java:113)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invokeNext(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:586)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.forwardInvoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:555)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunNamedDispatcher.forward(JRunNamedDispatcher.java:64)
    at coldfusion.license.JspLicenseServlet.service(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)
    at jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)
    at jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
    at jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$DownstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:320)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
    at jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$UpstreamMetrics.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:266)
    at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

if I use http://domain.com:9080/mytomcat-helloworld/pages/myhelloworld_jstl.jsp
all works as expected, any Ideas how to fix that ?

plesk version 10.4.4
tomcat version tomcat5-5.5.23-0jpp.22.el5_7

the war file i tried to deploy is from: http://www.michael-thomas.com/tech/apache/tomcat/tutorial_firststeps_tomcat/mytomcat-helloworld-war.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have fixed myself, it turns that coldfusion handled the jsp files, i placed to conf/vhost.conf:

```
RemoveHandler .jsp
JRunConfig Ignoresuffixmap true
```